# Table not centering in Outlook 365

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a table within a table and the table inside is not centering for some reason. I can't figure out why, maybe the VML is messing with it somehow? The `h3` tag above the table seems to center just fine. I have the background of the table to be blue just so I can see it clearer. Here's my email template:

```
<body>
  <div style="text-align: center; padding: -8px; font-family: brandon-grotesque-regular, Lato, sans-serif;">
    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" background="http://f52c38c7.ngrok.io/y6_warrior_challenge_email/images/bg_y6.png" valign="top" style="background-image: url('http://f52c38c7.ngrok.io/y6_warrior_challenge_email/images/bg_y6.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center; align: center;" width="680" height="960">

            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 510pt; height:720pt;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-white-texture-background_23-2148431731.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding: 48px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h3 style="color: #043d52; font-size: 32px; font-weight: bolder; padding: 32px 0 32px 0; margin: 0">
                      this is text
                    </h3>
                    <center>
                      <table align="center" style="background: blue; text-align: center;">

                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <img style="max-height: 145px; width: 100%;" alt="Shirt image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/350/536/354.jpg">
                            </td>



                            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <img style="max-height: 79px; width: 100%;" alt="Hat image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/350/536/354.jpg">
                            </td>

                            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <img style="max-height: 139px;" alt="Water bottle image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/350/536/354.jpg">
                            </td>


                            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <img style="max-height: 136px; width: 100%;" alt="Hoodie image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/350/536/354.jpg">
                            </td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>

                            <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <p style="color: #676767; font-weight: bolder;">text</p>
                            </td>

                            <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <p style="color: #676767; font-weight: bolder;">text</p>
                            </td>

                            <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <p style="color: #676767; font-weight: bolder;">text</p>
                            </td>

                            <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top !important; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                              <p style="color: #676767; font-weight: bolder;">text</p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is what it looks like in Outlook 365:

[image: email picture]

I highlighted the background to be gray so you can see it clearer, but the blue table is definitely not centered. I even tried using the `<center>` tag but it's still not working.

Comment: Try replacing width:680px in td with 100% as well, if doesn’t work set first table border=“1” for testing.

Comment: That did not seem to do anything. I see the border of the first table but the blue table is still not centered.

Comment: You have padding -8px it cannot have negative values. As a test you could try put second table inside h3. For testing using gmail is better it lets you inspect/manipulate email’s html with chrome dev tools.

Comment: It looks correct in gmail. I've tried to remove that padding but it didn't seem to make any difference. I've tested the email on live.outlook.com and gmail.com and also mobile and they all look correct. The only issue I have is with Outlook 365 as far as I know.

Comment: You can use new Microsoft Edge which based on Chrome to debug office365 website or debug using Internet Explorer with F12.